# How do I extend a Java generic interface with extends key words in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

If I have a java class like this:

```
public interface MyInterface<E extends Apple, EE extends Banana> {
    Class<E> foo();

    @Nullable
    EE bar(E e);
}
```

Comment: Could you write more details on what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to write the same code, but in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some implementations of Apple and Banana, then you just need to specify them as generics.

For example if i have such implementations of Apple and Banana in Java

```
public class AppleJavaImpl extends Apple {}

public class BananaJavaImpl extends Banana {}
```

then you can implement your Java MyInterface in Kotlin

```
class MyJavaInterfaceImplementationInKotlin: MyInterface<AppleJavaImpl, BananaJavaImpl> {
    override fun foo(): Class<AppleJavaImpl> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun bar(e: AppleJavaImpl?): BananaJavaImpl? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

the same applies with kotlin implementations of Apple and Banana

```
class AppleKotlinImpl: Apple()

class BananaKotlinImpl: Banana()

class MyJavaInterfaceImplementationInKotlin: MyInterface<AppleKotlinImpl, BananaKotlinImpl> {
    override fun foo(): Class<AppleKotlinImpl> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun bar(e: AppleKotlinImpl?): BananaKotlinImpl? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```